# Excel Ribbon - Enable Filter button for protected worksheet

Tags: xml, excel, ribbon

Using excel 2010 for protected sheets the auto filtering option on the Ribbon is greyed out. By however by right clicking I am still able to filter just fine despite the sheet being protected so this doesn't make much sense to me (but others seem to have the same problem http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=163585)

Is there a way to customize the ribbon xml to override this and enable to button permanently?

I've tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
<commands>   
<command idMso="Filter" enable="true"/>    
</commands>
</customUI>
```

But that had no effect. Would be grateful for any help!

EDIT.

My sheet is protected like so:

```
Sheet1.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, userinterfaceonly:=True, AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowDeletingColumns:=True, AllowInsertingColumns:=True
Sheet1.EnableAutoFilter = True
```

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/enable-autofilter-functionality-for-a-protected-worksheet-HA001098270.aspx

Comment: Follow these steps to enable AutoFilter functionality on protected worksheets. When you reach the second step, don't be afraid to browse through the list of functions for other tasks that you may want to re-enable.

1.On the Tools menu in Excel 2003 or 2002, point to Protection and then click Protect Sheet. The Protect Sheet dialog box appears.
2.From the Allow all users of this worksheet to list, select Use AutoFilter.

Comment: The the VBA section reads to match what you have done.  It might work properly from the menu options.

Comment: I think that link only applies to pre ribbon versions of excel? I don't have those menu options in 2010. Thanks though!